# Where are literal strings stored in memory?

Tags: c

I noticed that when defining 2 literal strings with the same string, they point to the same address. Then I wondered "where are literal strings stored in the memory?"

I have been looking on the internet for answers but I could not find anything clear that does actually answer my question and makes me understand the answer.

Comment: What do you mean "where"? In memory. When the program is running, most probably on RAM chips inside your computer.

Comment: Usually in the text section, same place as the code.  And yes, merging duplicate string literals is a common optimization.  [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gf-eliminate-duplicate-strings?view=msvc-170).  These are all strict implementation details.

Comment: Where string literals are stored and whether string literals overlap are different questions. In the 2018 C standard, 6.4.5 7 says “It is unspecified whether these arrays [the ones created for string literals] are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values…” This means a compiler, or other aspect of a C implementation, may overlap string literals but is not required to.

Comment: Try printf("%x\n", "hello"); to get the memory address, or gcc -S hello.c to print the assembly language to hello.s. There is a data segment for strings.

Comment: @frayser Pointers should be printed with `%p`, not `%x`